# I can't add photo to a contact when the contact was got (synchronized) from a google service

Tags: android, photo, contacts, synchronized

I have to ways to add photo to contact (see below). It work only when the contact was created on my device. It not work when the contact was got (synchronized) from a google service. And I have no any errors on runtime.
My device is working on **Android 4.1.1**

**First way** (from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html):

```
public static void writeDisplayPhoto(ContentResolver c, Bitmap contactPhoto, long personId) {
    // control args
    if ((contactPhoto == null)||(c==null)||(personId==0l)) {
        return;
    }
    // convert bitmap to byte
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    contactPhoto.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
    byte[] photo = bos.toByteArray();
    Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::writeDisplayPhoto()","personId: "+personId);
    // set tpoto to contact
    Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, personId),
            RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd =
            c.openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw");
        OutputStream os = fd.createOutputStream();
        os.write(photo);
        os.close();
        fd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::writeDisplayPhoto()",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Second way:**

```
public static void setContactPhoto(ContentResolver c, Bitmap contactPhoto, long personId) {
    if ((contactPhoto == null)||(c==null)||(personId==0l)) {
        return;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    contactPhoto.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    int photoRow = -1;
    String where = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + personId + " AND "
            + Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = c.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
        int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Data._ID);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
            Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::setContactPhoto()","photoRow: "+photoRow);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::setContactPhoto()",e.getMessage());
        if (cursor!=null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return;
    }
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, personId);
    values.put(Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
    values.put(Photo.PHOTO, bytes);
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    if (photoRow >= 0) {
        Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::setContactPhoto()","Update()");
        c.update(Data.CONTENT_URI, values, Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null);
    } else {
        Log.i("CallWidgetConfig::setContactPhoto()","Insert()");
        c.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```